# reading large (450000+ chars) strings from file

Tags: java, string, large-data

So, I'm dealing with integrating a legacy system. It produces a large text file, that prints instructions in one large string. Really large string. We're talking 450 000 characters or more.

I need to break this up in to lines, one per instruction. Each instruction is separated by a five digit code, where the code contains the number of characters in the next instruction.

My solution is writing a small java program that uses a buffered reader to read the file into a string, which is subsequently split into lines, and saved to a new file.

Any advice on handling this? Will a buffered reader be able to read this into a regular string? Am i doing this wrong?

Comment: `BufferedReader` should be able to read the data.

Comment: I would use `StringBuilder`

Comment: Actually I would process the file in chunks rather than putting it all into a `String` or `StringBuilder` if performance becomes an issue otherwise I would just load it all into a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: A clever solution would use input and output streams, and avoid reading the whole file into memory.

Comment: @brso05 how would you split the file into chunks?

Comment: @EricOlsvik - As bathsheba says - Use `fileInputStream#read(byte b[], int off, int len)` and keep reading bytes and converting them to String. PArt by part until you reach the end of input.

Comment: @EricOlsvik just read so many bytes then process then read some more bytes then process.  You said it is broken up by a 5 digit identifier just use regex to split then if there is anything left over just save the part that hasn't been processed and dump the rest before reading more bytes.

Comment: The Grep example on the official Java tutorials website (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/example/index.html) is very similar to what you are trying to do - it uses NIO, memory mapped files and regular expressions

Comment: @EricOlsvik first I would try reading the whole file if there isn't a performance issue than don't worry about it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use a buffered reader.

Work out the max size of an instruction and create a char[] of that size. Then do something like:

```
 reader.read(charArray, 0, 5);

 // parse the header

 reader.read(charArray, 0, lengthOfInstruction);

 String instruction = new String(charArray, 0, lengthOfInstruction);

 // do stuff with the instruction
```

You put this in a while loop that terminates when the file ends.

This might not be the most run-time efficient, but it's probably good enough and will be simple enough to get working.

Comment: I ended up doing almost exactly this.